# What is SIMBL Agent and why is it running on my machine?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

Is this something loaded by Apple or did it come with some third party app I must have downloaded.

Comment: One SIMBL Extension i have installed is "[The Unarchiever](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html)" which replaces the Finder File-Compression/decompression-Function and supports more Formats.

Comment: The Unarchiver is not a SIMBL plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SIMBL is not a part of Apple's Mac OS X package, but is an extension that can be used by other developers in their own work to extend applications where they may not have the original source code (like Safari). SIMBL-related files can be found either in `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins` or `~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins`.

Comment: For a more “technical” response, see the simbl page directly: http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php

Comment: For 10.7 & 10.8 see: https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL/

Answer (score -2):

It is usually used by SafariFlvSniffer.bundle which comes with a video downloader app.

Comment: It's used by a whole lot more than just that.

Comment: It is used by tons of other plugins. LastPass is the plugin I currently use that uses it. Definitely just check /Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins on your machine to see what is using it for you.