# “SIMBLAgent.app“ wants access to control

Tags: macos, security, mojave

I updated to Mojave yesterday and since then I get so many windows prompting up with the message “SIMBLAgent.app“ wants access to control... and I can get rid of all those windows comming.

Someone knows how to stop that?, any help is appreciated

Comment: Simbl is code that injects into apps especially safari to add extra functionality  it is not an apple app so you must have installed it

Comment: it just come up after upgrading to Mojave, I did install nothing.

Comment: It installs some things in /Library/Application Support/SIMBL - and i would have been installed by an admin on your machine before Mojave. Mojave has changed security so now causes these windows

Comment: The app is described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMBL

Comment: See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3919/what-is-simbl-agent-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-machine) on this site about what SIMBL is. The accepted answer may give you a clue as to where to find the app.

Comment: If I recall correctly SIMBL doesn't even work with SIP enabled, so unless you've disabled SIP it isn't doing anything anyway, and can be safely uninstalled.

Comment: Oh, yes. In the end I just uninstalled.

Answer (score 4):

These messages are part of the new security measures in Mojave. You are giving up control of your system to apps you may not intend, so you should deny those requests until you’re sure it is not malware or something you don’t want typing / interacting on your behalf.

Consider, an app could copy text like passwords or just watch for you typing / save screen captures using these permissions. Not all do, but you might use caution before disabling security.

You can try giving the app full disk access in the System Preferences.app > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access. Add the application by using the [+] icon or by dragging to the list.

[image: Mojave Full Disk Access]

Comment: which app should I give access? is it SIMBLA an app?, if yes I do not find it when using the [+] icon on that preferences...

Comment: On my computer SIMBLAgent.app can be found on Automation. Asking control for any service (even screen capture) !

Answer (score 2):

As per Gummibando's answer, you'll need to give permissions to SIMBLAgent.app in Security & Privacy in preferences:

The full path to the app should be:

```
/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/SIMBLAgent.app
```

However, it appears Automation is the correct category:
[image: SIMBLAgent.app Security Automation Prefs]

Comment: How does one add an application under Automation?  I can't seem to do this in Mojave but apparently I could in High Sierra, because there are two scripts I wrote before I upgraded last year, that both appear under Automation.  I can't figure out how to add a new one now.